# Multiple maven projects in eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have a multiple maven project like this:

```
root/
----war
----jar1
----jar2
----jar3
```

The war use jar1, jar2 and jar3

When I run a "mvn clean install", the compiled war is good and work fine in my server (jboss).
When I run a "mvn eclipse:eclipse" to generate my eclipse configuration, the build works but when I import my projects in eclipse (Indigo) and I publish my war in my server, jar1, jar2, jar3 are not publish.

In the war build path configuration, jar1, jar2, jar3 are well configured.

[image]

But when I look at the deployment assembly for the war project, I have the next error:

[image]

Here is my generated .classpath file for the war project:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.2_13/jsf-api-1.2_13.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.2_13/jsf-api-1.2_13-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
      <attribute value="jar:file:/Users/Kiva/java/repoMaven/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.2_13/jsf-api-1.2_13-javadoc.jar!/" name="javadoc_location"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/faces/jsf-impl/1.2_13/jsf-impl-1.2_13.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/faces/jsf-impl/1.2_13/jsf-impl-1.2_13-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/el/el-api/1.0/el-api-1.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/el/el-api/1.0/el-api-1.0-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
      <attribute value="/WEB-INF/lib" name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="/jar1"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="/jar2"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="/jar3"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
      <attribute value="/WEB-INF/lib" name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
</classpath>
```

Here is my eclipse plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't understand why it's wrong in my plugin configuration and why eclipse doesn't find jars.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try ticking your three jar dependency projects in Java Build Path - Order and Export.

Comment: Nothing change with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The jboss tools maven support plugin (install with jboss tools) break the link between projects. Uninstalling it will solve the problem.

It's possible to uninstall just the maven support and keep the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing in that case is: Don't use eclipse:eclipse anymore use the m2e plugin instead in relationship with Maven. Just simply do an import of the project. You should add m2e for wtp via Eclipse Marketplace. After that you should be able to deploy the war to the server.

Comment: I don't like m2eclipse especially since the new version. It bad manage some plugins and eclipse is very slow with m2eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to Eclipse [Multi-project Import/Export](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/projecttransfer/). I think it will cover your needs.

Comment: Nothing change with this plugin